# libGDX: Create TextButton with TextureRegion

Tags: android, libgdx, textures

I have a class where I load all my TextureRegions.

```
public class AssetLoader{

    public static TextureAtlas atlas;
    public static TextureRegion startButtonUp;
    public static TextureRegion startButtonDown;
    ...


    public static void loadAssets(){
        atlas = new TextureAtlas("images.atlas");   
        startButtonUp = atlas.findRegion("start_button_up");
        startButtonDown = atlas.findRegion("start_button_down");
    }
}
```

Now I want to create a TextButton in different classes which uses the TextureRegion from my AssetLoader. My actual workflow is:

```
    buttonsAtlas = new TextureAtlas("images.atlas");
    buttonSkin = new Skin();
    buttonSkin.addRegions(buttonsAtlas);

    font = new BitmapFont();

    stage = new Stage(new FitViewport(800, 400, camera), game.batch);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();

    textButtonStyle.up = buttonSkin.getDrawable("start_button_up");
    textButtonStyle.down = buttonSkin.getDrawable("start_button_down");

    textButtonStyle.font = font;

    button = new TextButton("Start", textButtonStyle);
    button.setHeight(AssetLoader.startButtonDown.getRegionHeight());
    button.setWidth(AssetLoader.startButtonDown.getRegionWidth());

    button.setPosition(0,100);

    stage.addActor(button);
    button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            /// start game
            game.setScreen(new PlayScreen(game));
            dispose();
        }
    });
```

But in this case I don't really need my AssetsLoader (expect the RegionWidth and RegionHeight) and it seems like a lot of code for every button in different classes. Is there any solution to solve this problem more efficient?

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: My question is, is this method so okay or is there any other efficient method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AssetLoader` class having a `textureAtlas` and reference of two `TextureRegion` that is  inside that textureAtlas.

If you want to rely on `AssetLoader`, create object of `AssetLoader` and use `atlas` of `AssetLoader` instead of `buttonsAtlas`(a new instance of textureAtlas).

or forget `AssetLoader`

```
button = new TextButton("Start", textButtonStyle);
button.setHeight(buttonsAtlas.findRegion("start_button_up").getRegionHeight());
button.setWidth(buttonsAtlas.findRegion("start_button_up").getRegionWidth());
```

---

It's good way to create all assets in one class and use all over the game, If possible you should use [AssetManager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets) in your game.